# Getting my expression to process the text in field

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, pyqgis-3, expression, text

I am building an expression, whose function is to return **True** if a characteristic is selected.

The expression requires two arguments, the Feature and the name of the layer.

If I enter the name of the layer as text it works properly. But if I enter a field containing the name of the layer it does not work, even if the record contains exactly the name.

Here is the code of the expression:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def isSelected(entidad, capa, feature, parent):
    proy= QgsProject.instance()
    capap= proy.mapLayersByName(capa)[0]
    les= list(capap.getSelectedFeatures())
    boolean=False
    for f in les:
        if f.id() == entidad.id():
            boolean= True
            break
        else:
            continue
    return boolean
```

**Note:**

- The equivalent function, exists (`is_selected`) but does not work properly in my QGIS, version 3.4
- The code works properly on the console

Comment: Probably the last thing you want to hear, but in 3.16 this works as expected, both with `isSelected( $currentfeature, "<fieldname>" )` notation as well as `isSelected( $currentfeature, attribute( '<fieldname>' ) )`, where the field `<fieldname>` holds a string literal with a valid layer name. Are you certain your literals are not wrapped in any way? Did the internals for `mapLayersByName` change in any way between versions, removing or adding wrapping characters?

Comment: Also, what exactly 'does not work'? Any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution worked for me.

- Add this script to the "Function Editor":

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def isSelected(feat, field, feature, parent):
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(field)[0]
    for f in layer.getSelectedFeatures():
        if f['fid'] == feat['fid']:
            return 1 # True
    return 0 # False
```

- Run this expression for layer `A` (see the picture below):

```py
isSelected(
  get_feature('C', 'fid', "fid"),
  lyr_field
)
```

Explanation:

- `get_feature('C', 'fid', "fid")`:

  Return the feature of `C` matching (`fid` in `C` == `"fid"` in `A`)
- `QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(field)[0]`:

  Return the layer matching the `lyr_field` value (`B` here) of the feature in `A`.
- `layer.getSelectedFeatures()`:

  Get selected features in `B`.
- `if f['fid'] == feat['fid']`:

  If `fid` value of one of the selected features in `B` exists in `C` then return `1`, else return 0

If `get_feature('C', 'fid', "fid")` returns `None`, the expression returns nothing.

I used `aa` field to populate.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, too. I hope I didn't write anything wrong. :)

Answer (score 4):

See below the changed code: you will not need the parameter "entidad" you can use the default parameter "feature" instead:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def isSelected(capa, feature, parent):
    proy= QgsProject.instance()
    capap= proy.mapLayersByName(capa)[0]
    les= list(capap.getSelectedFeatures())
    boolean=False
    for f in les:
        if f.id() == feature.id():
            boolean= True
            break
        else:
            continue
    return boolean
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but feature can be specified or is it a feature of the layer on which the expression is performed?
The idea is to apply an aggregate expression, the entity variable is a feature of a layer different from the current one